# How to get value in item adding on a remote event receiver for a taxonomy field?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, remote-event-receiver

I have the following code which returns me a value like this:

> "1;#empresa1|6507d102-8c2c-4072-b8bc-c4c67636e091"

The value I am interested in its: `empresa1`

Is there anyway I can get it in an item adding event on a remote event receiver without string manipulation??

```
public static SPRemoteEventResult CreateClientSiteAndUpdateSiteOnList(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
     SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
     try
     {
         using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
         {
              if (clientContext != null)
              {
                  var afterProperties = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties;
                  afterProperties["Nombre_x0020_Cliente"].ToString()
```

Comment: That format is fixed. So there is no problem with using String Manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection txColl = afterProperties["Nombre_x0020_Cliente"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
if (txColl != null) {
    foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue t in txColl) {
        if (t.Label != null)
            //t.Label
    }
}
```

Comment: its a remote event receiver, that doesnt work, TaxonomyFieldValueCollection is null

Comment: Ok if you try `TaxonomyFieldValue t = afterProperties["Nombre_x0020_Cliente"] as TaxonomyFieldValue` are you getting the object?

Comment: also null, check comment